# List.ToArray() returns nothing (System.Int32[])

Tags: c#, arrays

Why do the List returns nothing when it is converted .ToArray()
I had to loop overeach item, But I need to return array.

```
public static int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
     List<int> empty_fill = new List<int>();
    for (int CurrentPosition = 0; CurrentPosition < nums.Length - 1; CurrentPosition++)
    {
        for (int NextValue = CurrentPosition; NextValue < nums.Length - 1; NextValue++)
        {
            if (nums[CurrentPosition] + nums[NextValue + 1] == target)
            {
                empty_fill.Add(nums[CurrentPosition]);
                empty_fill.Add(nums[NextValue + 1]);

            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    if (empty_fill.Count == 0)
    {
        //empty_fill = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Nothing to match...");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var s in empty_fill)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }

    return empty_fill.ToArray();
}
```

Test

```
int[] arra = new int[] { 2, 5, 3, 7, 6 };
Console.WriteLine(TwoSum(arra, 8));

OutPut
    2
    6
    5
    3
    System.Int32[] <<< I need this to be replaced with [2,6,5,3]
```

Comment: `return empty_fill.ToArray();` returns *new* array, it doesn't modify existining one `nums`. You, probably, want `arra = TwoSum(arra, 8);` and then `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", arra));`

Comment: Try `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', TwoSum(arra, 8)));` This will print each number inside of the array seperated by a whitespace. By just calling `Console.WriteLine(TwoSum(arra, 8));` the `ToString()` method of `Int32[]` will be called implicitly which will not return the items of the array but by default the datatype name. In this case `System.Int32[]`.

Comment: It doesn't return "nothing" - it returns a list. The problem is that you try to print the list to the console, not the _contents_ of the list. See the marked duplicate and other comments for a few options.

Comment: I don't know where was my head , I lost it for few seconds :D,
 Anyway the (string.Join ) did the trick, thanks for you all <3